# Efficiently create bitmap for map markers

Tags: android, bitmap, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using android google maps v2 and I am creating map markers and assigning a bitmap.  I am getting the bitmap from my assets directory.  The reason I get them from assets is that the path I am using to find the 'right' icon is dynamic.

My question is should I be saving the underlying bitmap so that I can reuse it again and again.  I read:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

but frankly a lot of there really big sample project was over my head.

Should I be recreating the bitmap each time I need to pass that to a marker for creation, or should I read each bitmap( up to a limit) into memory and save them for reuse.

Each will be drawn on the map regardless so I am not sure I can reuse anyway.

Example:  I have 300 markers on the map, with 20 different possible bitmaps.  I.E. about 15% are the same marker icon.

Answer (score 4):

Since bitmap decoding is quite expensive operation I would definitely recommend to go with bitmap caching. Especially in your case when the number of unique bitmaps is much smaller than number of markers on a map. Simple `[LruCache][1]` - based in-memory cache would work just fine. You just need to be careful about how much memory do you use for your cache.

Here is a good example of how to implement in-memory cache:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

**Follow up**

Just thought about this a bit more and you can do even better job here. Instead of caching bitmaps you can cache `BitmapDescriptor` for every unique bitmap you have. This way you can get some extra performance by avoiding making calls to `BitmapDescriptorFactory` every time you need to create a marker

**UPDATE**

Here is what I mean:

```
LruCache<String, BitmapDescriptor> cache;

private void initCache()
{
    //Use 1/8 of available memory
    cache = new LruCache<String, BitmapDescriptor>((int)(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 8));
}

private void addMarker(LatLng position, String assetPath)
{
    MarkerOptions opts = new MarkerOptions();
    opts.icon(getBitmapDescriptor(assetPath));
    opts.position(position);
    mMap.addMarker(opts);
}

private BitmapDescriptor getBitmapDescriptor(String path) {
    BitmapDescriptor result = cache.get(path);
    if (result == null) {
        result = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromAsset(path);
        cache.put(path, result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  Quick follow-up on your answer.  I modified some code to add the inBitmap to my options (if I have one cached).  However I am not 100% sure its using the bitmap I am giving it.  Is there a way that I can tell?

Comment: it is not quite what I meant. `inBitmap` is used by `BitmapFactory` (not `BitmapDescriptorFactory`). `inBitmap` can help you to reuse existing pre-allocated bitmap for decoding another bitmap, but what I meant - is to cache `BitmapDescriptor`

Comment: @PavelDudka Thank you for your answer, but it does not include a way to properly calculate the size of BitmapDescriptor
```@Override protected int sizeOf(...)```

Comment: Can anyone confirm that this will improve map scrolling performance AFTER all the markers are rendered? Or is the performance gain only when first adding the markers?